# Understanding a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, dom-events, hide, show

I don't really know anything about Javascript and I am trying to understand this piece of code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick='toggle_detail(this, "value-computations", "3")' ">
```

The part I don't understand relates to the portion that indicates `onClick='toggle_detail..` Is this a custom function or a native Javascript function?

Ultimately I am looking to re-write this anchor tag so that on click it displays `<div class="details">` and on the second click it hides the content of `<div class="details">`.

All help is greatly appreciated, as I know nothing about Javascript.

Comment: It's custom, look for the function's definition somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toggle_detail is a custom function. It should be defined somewhere else on the page, or in a script that the page links to. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/javascript)'s a good reference/tutorial on javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct. It's a custom function. It has been defined elsewhere, either in a `< script >` tag that actually shows code, or it's been referenced in a `< script >` tag that has a `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle detail is a custom function.

A well written toggle_detail function wouldn't require you to change the anchor tag at all. Usually, a function that called toggle would flip a setting back and forth, like visibility of another element